# Como fazer um menu flutuante e que mudar de estilo conforme movimento a scroll?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Como fazer o menu fixo fluatuante com rolagem de scroll como o do site:

https://bootstrapmade.com/demo/BizPage/

Repare que quando desco a scroll o background do menu muda para preto.

Answer (score 2):

Com um jQuery simples vc faz isso. Nesse exemplo quando a pessoa rolar a tela 40px eu vou colocar uma classe `.ativo` na `Navbar` com `id menu`. Quando ele rolar de volta eu retiro a classe `.ativo`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor. Eu usei pro Bootstrap 4 já que vc colocou a tag Bootstrap, mas funciona em qualquer código, desde que tenha jQuery como o Bootstrap

O único CSS que inclui foi pra estilizar a `nav` para ficar parecido com o exemplo.

**OBS:** Deixei comentários no código pra facilitar o entendimento

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 40) {               // se rolar 40px ativa o evento
    $("#menu").addClass("ativo");    //coloca a classe "ativo" no id=menu
  } else {
    $("#menu").removeClass("ativo"); //se for menor que 40px retira a classe "ativo" do id=menu
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 75rem;
  padding-top: 7.5rem;
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/400/200?image=6);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
}

#menu {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) !important;
  padding: 1.5rem 1rem;
  transition: all 500ms linear;
}
#menu.ativo {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) !important;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
        aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Navbar example</h1>
        <p class="lead">This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how fixed to top navbar works. As you
            scroll, it will remain fixed to the top of your browser's viewport.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs »</a>
    </div>
</main>
```